# Jquery: Add rel attribute to <a> tags within all <li> tags of a certain class

Tags: jquery, attributes, lightbox, addition, rel

I'm trying to add a 
`rel="lightframe"` attribute to all my 'edit' links within my `admin_links_node_edit` class.

```
<li class="admin_links_node_edit">
<a href="[link]" title="Edit">Edit</a>
</li>
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
$('.admin_links_node_edit a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightframe'); 
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to use each(). jQuery's selectors will do it for you :)

```
$('.admin_links_node_edit a').attr('rel', 'lightframe')
```

The above code will do the trick.

Comment: Potentially buggy and vulnerable code. Do not do this.
If you have links with other "rel" attributes it will be overwritten.
If you loose "noopener" attribute - it jeopardizes your site for window.opener attack.

Answer (score 1):

If `admin_links_node_edit` is reused among other elements, you'll want to specify the element you're working on (`li` in this case). In addition, as Vijay Dev said, each() isn't needed, as attr() works on every element in the selector. Therefore:

```
$("li.admin_links_node_edit a").attr('rel','lightframe');
```