# Javascript and Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add Lightbox to a image which is output by Javascript. The image link is built up dynamically so thats why I am doing it this way!

I have looked on S.O. but no luck with what is already there...

The code currently is;

```
$("#imgMain img").attr("src","/_images/multi/"+productCode+"/"+imgCodeAlt+"_l.jpg");
```

And i somehow need to append it with rel="lightbox"

Thanks in advance :)

Shaun

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767025/jquery-add-rel-attribute-to-a-tags-within-all-li-tags-of-a-certain-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -

```
$("#imgMain img").attr({
  src: '/_images/multi/"+productCode+"/"+imgCodeAlt+"_l.jpg',
  rel: 'lightbox'
});
```

Comment: Just needed to change the outer quotes to double insead of single quotes.                                               $("#imgMain img").attr({
                                                  rel: 'lightbox',
                                                  src: "/_images/multi/"+productCode+"/"+imgCodeAlt+"_l.jpg"
                                             });

Answer (score 1):

Try :

**JQuery**

```
$("#imgMain img").attr("rel","lightbox");
```